# How to set I18n.t in Rails 3.2 for individual user?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, rails-i18n

Our rails app sets the `I18n.t` in a file under `config/initializers`:

```
I18n.default_locale = 'EN' if Rails.env.production?
```

This line of code is executed before a user logs in. We would like to set the I18n.t environment based on individual user after she/he logs in. Is there a way doing this individual user based I18n.t?

Comment: btw. it is best practice to use lowercase strings (or symbols) to set locales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The the `I18n.locale` in a `before_filter` in your `application_controller` after you identified the `current_user`.

```
before_filter :set_locale

private
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = current_user.preferred_locale if current_user
end
```

Note: You might need to change `current_user` and `preferred_locale` to match the naming of these instances and attributes in your application.

See Rails guides about [setting and passing the locale](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-the-locale).